# Persist Prometheus data from a Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I'm running Prometheus and Grafana from docker-compose and basically it works. But I don't get my prometheus data to persist on my host machine.

As soon as I switch my volume settings from

```yaml
---
version: "3.3"
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.43.0
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./assets/config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

volumes:
  prometheus_data:
```

to

```yaml
---
version: "3.3"
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.43.0
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./assets/config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro
      - ./container_data/prometheus:/prometheus
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
```

the data is no longer visible in my Grafana UI and the now new `container_data` folder on my host machine is empty.

Anyone got an idea how I can persist my data so that statistics survive a reboot of my docker-stack?

Addionally I would like to run Prometheus with the same user I use on my Ubuntu 22.10 host. But that is an afterthought for the moment.